# Using MacOS shortcuts in IntelliJ running on Ubuntu in Parallels Desktop

Tags: macos, ubuntu, intellij-idea, parallels

I have Ubuntu 18.04 running in Parallels Desktop environment on my Mac (MacOS Catalina). 
IntelliJ is installed in this Ubuntu environment.

I want to use MacOS layout in my IntelliJ. Under Ubuntu, after selecting "macOS" keyboard layout, shortcuts with cmd key are using Meta key.

I installed Gnome Tweaks and enabled Win->Meta mapping.
Shortcuts like Meta-B work - they're not used by the system. However, many others don't. Some of them are listed in Settings->Keyboards (i.e. Super-S), some of them are intercepted elsewhere (i.e. Super-O):

`org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys video-rotation-lock ['<Super>o']`

Why after enabling Win->Meta mapping the cmd key is still treated as Super by the system?

Is there any better way of dealing with this issue other than unbinding all of these keymappings?

Apparently, looks like Gnome Tweaks makes changes using setxkbmap - I also trying playing with mod4 mapping in xmodmap, didn't help much.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: BTW there's a feature request to switch the modifier key throughout IDE: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229539

Comment: Have you tried [these recommendations](https://superuser.com/questions/433724/how-do-i-disable-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-menu-in-linux-mint-13)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no good way to solve this via tuning IDE, but you can try making Linux version of [macOS keymap](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13258-macos-keymap) plugin (see the plugin sources as an example, or public sources of [any keymap plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/VisualStudioKeymap4IntelliJ)).